# Remote Images not displaying after running Magmi

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magmi

I've installed Magmi, configured it and installed it too

Iam able to get products into my site, BUT prob is: Iam unable to see any image, since image urls all are from remote..

My image url looks like: http://www.fashion58.com/itemimages/SMS032-navy.jpg

Even iam not sure whether to change 'image renaming' or not, BUT at end all I need is : my remore image urls should able to display in my site..

Awaiting response!

**EDITED**: 
**My feed Column names are:**  `store,websites,type,attribute_set,is_affiliate_product,status,visibility,qty,is_in_stock,tax_class_id,weight,name,meta_keyword,description,sku,manufacturer,price,merchant_buy_link,image,main_category,color,for,shoe_type,short_description,thumbnail,category_ids,merchant_name,merchant_id,small_image`

**A)** and Do I really need to use '**Image attributes processor**' plugin inorder to display remote image urls?  or else Magmi just enough to render images for remote image urls?

**B)** If YES for '**Image attributes processor**', what settings I need to change in it?

**C)** What could be still wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image URL is incorrect.  It needs to be an absolute URL of an actual image (not just a page with the image embedded on it).

```
http://www.site.com/path/to/imagename.jpg
```

Comment: now i given correct image url..(pls kindly check above again) my feed has remote image urls, and column names related to image are: remote_image_url and  remote_thumbnail_image_url

Comment: Your column names are not correct.  Read the Documentation. http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor

Comment: now I renamed these 2 columns "remote_image_url and remote_thumbnail_image_url "  to "image and thumbnail" , even then iam not getting images displayed on my site from feed.

pls kindly help me on this..

Comment: I just edited above in my main post, could you please read that again!